# #{facesContext} EL expression not resolved at runtime

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, el, jsf-1.2

I am working on JSF 1.x
On an example stated in JavaServer Faces in Action.

My EL expression of 'Faces Context' is not executing at run time in command button on retrieving the image.

**My Project Structure is as follows:**

[image: Structure]

I have not used any Java code in this example,
And it contains only one Login Page.

**The login.jsp is as follows:**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>


<f:view>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function set_image(button, image){
            button.src = img;
        }
    </script>

    <title><h:outputText value="ProjectTrack" /></title>
</head>

<body>

    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">

            <h:graphicImage url="/images/logo.png"
                    alt="Welcome to ProjectTrack" title="Welcome to ProjectTrack"
                    width="149" height="160" />


            <h:panelGrid columns="3" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" headerClass="login-heading">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="ProjectTrack" />
                </f:facet>

                <h:outputLabel for="userNameInput" >
                    <h:outputText value="Enter your user name: " />
                </h:outputLabel>

                <h:inputText id="userNameInput" size="20" maxlength="30" required="true">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="30"/>
                </h:inputText>

                <h:message for="userNameInput" />

                <h:outputLabel for="passwordInput">
                    <h:outputText value="Password"/>
                </h:outputLabel>

                <h:inputSecret id="passwordInput" size="20" maxlength="20" required="true">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="15" />
                </h:inputSecret>

                <h:message for="passwordInput" />

                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:commandButton  action="success" 
                                image="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/submit.gif" 
                                onmouseover="set_image(this, '#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/submit_over.gif');"
                                onmouseout="set_image(this, '#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/submit.gif');" 
                            />
                </h:panelGroup>

            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</body>
</f:view>
    </html>
```

**My Deployment Descriptor web.xml is as follows:**

```
<web-app version="2.5"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>Project Track</display-name>
    <description>Sample Project</description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

**Faces-config.xml is as follows:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC
     "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.0//EN"
     "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_0.dtd">

<faces-config>

    <application>
        <message-bundle>ptrackResources</message-bundle>
    </application>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/login.jsp</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/inbox.jsp</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>failure</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login.jsp</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

**My Maven Dependencies are as follows:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.achutha.labs</groupId>
  <artifactId>03JsfExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>03JsfExample</name>
  <description>Project Track</description>

  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2_14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2_14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- EL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8090/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/balaji</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

The Application Ran successfully. But the Image for submit button is not displaying which is retrieved through a run time expression.

**Browser Display:**

[image: Browser Display]

I have configured my JBoss tools, from which i can see the preview which evaluates the expression and displays the submit button before deployment:

**Eclipse Screen Shot:**

[image: Eclipse Screen Shots]

The EL expression used in  is not evaluating at runtime.

```
<h:commandButton  action="success" 
                                image="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/submit.gif" 
                                onmouseover="set_image(this, '#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/submit_over.gif');"
                                onmouseout="set_image(this, '#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/submit.gif');" 
                            />
```

I have to use JSF 1.x and cannot upgrade it to JSF 2.
Please suggest me the solution, and help me know what is going wrong.

My problem is similar to the problem stated here in this link:
[FacesContext not resolved at run-time](http://www.java.net/node/703730)

**EDIT:**

I just added a Debug statement in `login.jsp` which is as follows:

```
<h:outputText value=" Debug test for EL exp : #{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/submit.gif" />
```

**Debug Result:**

[image: Debug Result]

The expression is getting evaluated at runtime, 
But I feel the result must not contain `/balaji/images/submit.gif`,
And it should only contain `/images/submit.gif`.

Comment: Have you tried with `#{request.contextPath}` instead ?

Comment: Which URL do you use to access the page ?

Comment: http://localhost:8090/balaji

I am using Tomcat 7 Server.

Comment: Have you tried `.face` instead of `.jsp` in your config ?

Comment: #{request.contextPath} Did not work.
I am getting the same result.

Comment: Where should i change it to '.face' in my config ??
 please specify.

Comment: I don't do Maven, but your list of "Maven Dependencies" is rather scary. JSP/Servlet/EL are supposed to be provided by the container already and absolutely not by the webapp itself. Shouldn't you be using `<scope>provided</scope>` on them in your pom?

Comment: I like a complete question, but this is ridiculous. We don't need pictures of your web pages. Actually in this case the title alone is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implicit EL variable `#{facesContext}` is only available in JSF2. The shorthand `#{request}` as suggested in a comment is only available in Facelets.

You're using JSF1 on JSP. You should be using `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` instead.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `<h:commandButton image>` is already context-relative. You don't need to specify it in there. It's only mandatory for your JS mouseover/out functions.

Comment: @baluc,
Thanks for your remark.
I am afraid to say the old EL is working fine, 
Please check the edited question.

But I am facing a new problem.
I removed the EL phrase in all the lines,
I am getting the submit button.
But, It is not executing the javascript, and the image is not changing.
I also added a alrt function to both onmouseover, onmouseout events. 
And its not executing even the alerts.

Please help me out with it.

Comment: @baluc...
Thats right, you figured the problem before i made my comment.
How to solve this issue??

Answer (score 1):

You have set an `url-pattern` containing `/faces/*`, you must access your JSF pages using this pattern or change to another pattern.
Example of other pattern:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.face</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>Disallow direct access to the XHTML Documents</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
  </security-constraint>
```

Comment: If `FacesServlet` wasn't invoked, OP would not have seen output labels and input texts at all.

Comment: That makes sense, I never used JSF 1 with JSP

Comment: @Christophe Roussy,
 Expressing is working fine. Plez look at the debug i have added on edited question.

Now the problem is in javascript.
Please help me out with the new problem with onmouseover and onmouseout events which is not executing my JS.

Comment: create a new question for that