# Javascript events not working in JSF command button

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, dom-events, jsf-1.2

I am working on JSF 1.x
On an example stated in JavaServer Faces in Action.

The javascript invoked on command button is not working. Both onmouseover/out events are 
not executing the methods.

**My Project Structure is as follows:**

[image: Structure]

I have not used any Java code in this example,
And it contains only one Login Page.

**The login.jsp is as follows:**

```
   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>


<f:view>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function set_image(button, image){
            button.src = img;
        }
    </script>

    <title><h:outputText value="ProjectTrack" /></title>
</head>

<body>

    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">

            <h:graphicImage url="/images/logo.png"
                    alt="Welcome to ProjectTrack" title="Welcome to ProjectTrack"
                    width="149" height="160" />


            <h:panelGrid columns="3" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" headerClass="login-heading">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="ProjectTrack" />
                </f:facet>

                <h:outputLabel for="userNameInput" >
                    <h:outputText value="Enter your user name: " />
                </h:outputLabel>

                <h:inputText id="userNameInput" size="20" maxlength="30" required="true">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="30"/>
                </h:inputText>

                <h:message for="userNameInput" />

                <h:outputLabel for="passwordInput">
                    <h:outputText value="Password"/>
                </h:outputLabel>

                <h:inputSecret id="passwordInput" size="20" maxlength="20" required="true">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="15" />
                </h:inputSecret>

                <h:message for="passwordInput" />

                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:commandButton  action="success" 
                                image="/images/submit.gif" 
                                onmouseover="set_image(this, '/images/submit_over.gif'); alert('button: ' + this );"
                                onmouseout="set_image(this, '/images/submit.gif'); alert('button: ' + this ); " 
                            />
                </h:panelGroup>

            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:outputText value=" Debug test for EL exp : #{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/submit.gif" />
    </h:form>
</body>
</f:view>
    </html>
```

**My Deployment Descriptor web.xml is as follows:**

```
<web-app version="2.5"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>Project Track</display-name>
    <description>Sample Project</description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

**Faces-config.xml is as follows:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE faces-config PUBLIC
     "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JavaServer Faces Config 1.0//EN"
     "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_0.dtd">

<faces-config>

    <application>
        <message-bundle>ptrackResources</message-bundle>
    </application>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/login.jsp</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/inbox.jsp</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>failure</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login.jsp</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

**My Maven Dependencies are as follows:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.achutha.labs</groupId>
  <artifactId>03JsfExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>03JsfExample</name>
  <description>Project Track</description>

  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2_14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2_14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- EL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8090/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/balaji</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

The Application Ran successfully. But the Image for submit button is not displaying which is retrieved through a run time expression.

**Browser Display:**

[image]

The JavaScript is not invoking events declared.

```
<h:commandButton  action="success" 
                                    image="/images/submit.gif" 
                                    onmouseover="set_image(this, '/images/submit_over.gif'); alert('button: ' + this );"
                                    onmouseout="set_image(this, '/images/submit.gif'); alert('button: ' + this ); " 
                                />
```

I have to use JSF 1.x and cannot upgrade it to JSF 2.
Please suggest me the solution, and help me know what is going wrong.

**Previously:**

As stated in the question [#{facesContext} EL expression not resolved at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002141/facescontext-el-expression-not-resolved-at-runtime)
I was using the following statement for command button.

```
<h:commandButton  action="success" 
                                image="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/submit.gif" 
                                onmouseover="set_image(this, '#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/submit_over.gif');"
                                onmouseout="set_image(this, '#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/submit.gif');" 
                            />
```

I just added a Debug statement in `login.jsp` which is as follows:

```
<h:outputText value=" Debug test for EL exp : #{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/submit.gif" />
```

**Debug Result:**

[image: Debug Result]

The expression is getting evaluated at run time, (but the submit image was not seen) that eliminates the previous problem.
Hence I removed the EL statements, and replaced them with relative path without project name appended.

Comment: Don't you thing that you work on some newer JSF version?

Comment: Check the generated HTML for your JSF page. Then just make the tests in plain HTML/JS. Once it works, just make the changes in your JSF code. By the way, no need to show all the non-related code, pom.xml, project structure, deployment file, and all kind of info that is won't help to analyze the real problem causes.

Comment: If javascript doesn't work in a project, you're bound to get cues first from the developer's console of your browser. I'd start there. Also there's too much noise in your question. Please try to trim it down to code only.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the mistake was.

My javascript code was wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function set_image(button, image){
            button.src = img;
        }
    </script>
```

I changed the img to image :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function set_image(button, image){
            button.src = image;
        }
    </script>
```

Then the events started working fine.
But the 2nd image 'submit_over.gif' was not retrieving for display.

I then added the EL expression to the events :

```
<h:commandButton  action="success" 
                                image="/images/submit.gif" 
                                onmouseover="set_image(this, '#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/submit_over.gif');"
                                onmouseout="set_image(this, '#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images/submit.gif');" 
                            />
```

This solved all my problems.

Thanks everyone for the comments and suggestion.
Your suggestion worked.